# need to pass a php array constructed from a txt file back to an ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I am banging my head with this for quite a while now exploring on you tube and stackoverflow for similar situations to find a solution to this issue with no luck whatsoever, so I hope someone can help if I ask directly...

Now to explain my issue...I have a php page that has a select field aswell as a text field which are supposed to interract between themselves using the combination of javascript and PHP. Now the select field has a list of countries which I get the value from with this code:

`var select = $("select[name='from_country'] option:selected").text();`

where `from_country` is the name of the select field.

The text field on the other hand triggers from a keydown anonimous jquery function which then is supposed to use the "select" variable value to pass it via an ajax call to a PHP function which then on its end should from the selected country value find a txt file with the appropriate name of the country and contains a list of its cities and put it into an array which then should be returned back to the javascript function that made the ajax call and populate a variable called availableTags which is used by a remote function that autocomplets the text field with the appropriate names of the selected country.

Now my issue here is that if I try this only with javascript and put the availableTags variable equal to a function in that same function which gets the values all listed in that function as an array it works fine, but is very ugly code and I want to clean it up by using an ajax call to fetch those notepad files with php and then return them back in an array which would be encapsulated into the avaialbleTags variable.

Here is how the code looks like after my last attempts to solve the issues:

javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#tag" ).keydown(function(){


//here needs to come code that checks which country is selected and fetch an appropriate //array of cities corresponding to the selected country(you will need to send an ajax //request to a PHP file which will check the country and fetch the appropriate external file //with tags to be used as an array to be used in the autocomplete function below!!

        var select = $("select[name='from_country'] option:selected").text();

    var availableTags = $.ajax({
                        url: "find_cities_by_country.php",
                        data: {country_to_find : select},
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(data){

                                return data;
                            }   
                        }); 
//the autocomplete is the external function
        $( "#tag" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
            });

        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source:  availableTags
            });


    });
});
```

PHP file:

```
$country_to_find = $_POST ["country_to_find"];

if(!empty($country_to_find)){


//reads the file with the name of the value passed from the javascript function
//and then appends it's contents to the $data[] array in the while loop 

      $file_to_read = $country_to_find.".txt";

    $fh = fopen ($file_to_read, 'r');

    while(!feof($fh))
          {
          $data[] .= fgets($fh);//."<br>";
          }


    fclose($fh);

//json_encode should pass the data as an array to the javascript function that made
//the ajax call to this function 

    echo json_encode($data);    
}
```

If I forgot to add some relevant information to help you answer my question, please let me know, thx.

Answer (score 0):

## Fixed code

```
var availableTags = {};
$.ajax({
    url: "find_cities_by_country.php",
    data: {country_to_find : select},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        availableTags = data;
    }   
});
```

### Explanation

`$.ajax()` returns [jqXHR object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR), not response data. You should assign your `data` variable (parsed JSON) to the `availableTags` variable.

`availableTags` was declared in the top, because it needs to be in context of anonymous function passed to the `$( "#tag" ).keydown()` method.

Comment: Hey, maybe I wasn't clear but I want the returned data to be an array of non key associated values that I encapsulate within the availableTags variable which should be an array of var "data" returned values which then the external function uses as a reference for tags when users start typing. I have no use of an object...all I need is the data returned to be transfered into an array which equals availableTags that should look like this: availableTags = [
"value1",
"value2",
"value3"

]

Comment: maybe what I am trying to do here ain't even possible, but I need some1 to tell me that because I am very confused on this matter and don't think I can figure it out by myself as of my current knowledge on the matter...

Comment: Post here your resulting JSON (which passed from PHP to browser) — i'll rewrite code to make it an array